# Animating the process of creating a 3d scene

Tags: rendering, animation

I have a few completed renders and I would like to quickly show how they were made via a quick animation. Have you ever seen a behind-the-scenes look at movie's vfx where first you'll see a frame of the raw footage, then a rough 3d model will slide onto the screen, then a smoother model with basic color slides on top of that, then a textured model, then a final render with proper lighting and such? I would like to recreate that but I'm unsure of how to go about it.

(this gif is a good example of what I mean) 
https://digitalsynopsis.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/movies-before-after-green-screen-cgi-hobbit.gif

Comment: If you already have the finished scene that should be pretty straightforward, just compose a video of it without post processing, then without materials or textures, perhaps one with wireframes and one without modifiers etc. It is really up to you what is relevant to show. What part exactly are you stuck in?

Answer (score 2):

After setting up the animation in blender, render out the final video. Then do an [opengl render](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/opengl.html#rendering) of the 3d scene, this will render the 3d viewport version of the animation. You can adjust the [display](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/properties/panels.html) and [object](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/properties/display.html) properties to adjust how the scene looks.

Once you have the two videos, add them to the [Video Sequence Editor](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/vse/introduction.html), then you can [cut the strips](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/vse/sequencer/editing.html#cut-soft-at-frame) so that each is visible at different times. You can add a [wipe effect](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/vse/sequencer/strips/effects/wipe.html) to switch between each video or you can use [animated masks](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/vse/sequencer/properties/modifiers.html) for more elaborate transitions.